# magento 2.2.6 theme responsive issue

Tags: theme, css, rwd

I run several websites with a "responsive" template. The thing is, the template is not really responsive....(And the developpers have dropped support on it...)
the mobile stylesheet seems completely messed up. You can see by yourself on https://www.oxyform.be.
Is there a way to fix this ? (other than set up a new theme :/ )
Thank you for guiding me.

Comment: the below answer is going to be the best solution for this problem

Comment: Ben Cook is right. It should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fixed width on quite a few elements:

[image]

To fix this edit the CSS to something like this:

```
max-width: 1170px;
width: 100%;
```

As for where to make this change I can't say without seeing the theme, it will likely be a SCSS or LESS file.

Now your site is responsive again:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, you solved it! thank you so much !

Comment: Glad to hear it worked @JGCabanas - Can you mark my answer as accepted please?

Comment: I just did ! thanks again.